# Calculating dataframe field value from another dataframe based on matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use values of one dataframe to calculate values of a new dataframe for the same date and hour. However, I am having difficulties with the syntax:

I want to go through my `dfEnergy` dataframe, and for every date and hour in it, I want to use "power" values from df dataframe, to calculate "energy" in dfEnergy dataframe. I have tried using functions but for some reason I cannot get it to work.

```
def find_power(date, hour, df):
    mask = np.logical_and.reduce([
        df['date'] ==date,
        df['hour'] == hour
    ])
    df_tmp = df.loc[mask, :]
    energy = sum(0.25*df_tmp['power'])
    df_tmp.iloc[0:0]
    return energy
#
## create result
for i in range (1, len(dfEnergy)):
    date = dfEnergy['date'].values[i]
    hour = dfEnergy['hour'].values[i]
    dfEnergy['energy'].values[i]=find_power(date,hour,df)
```

However, df_tmp is increasing with each iteration and for `dfEnergy['energy']` value I get as a results integers from 0 to 4 while the value should be real. Each hour has 4 values from which I want to calculate the energy, so I am suspecting that values are being counted.

Comment: `dfEnergy['hour'.values[i]` did you forget a `]` after `'hour'`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, I will update error message. Thanks!

Comment: `sum()` not `sum[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with forum help. Here is the solution:

```
def find_power(date, hour, df):
    mask = 0
    mask = np.logical_and.reduce([
        df['date'] ==date,
        df['hour'] == hour
    ])
    df_tmp = df.loc[mask, :]
    energy = sum(0.25*df_tmp['power'])
    df_tmp.iloc[0:0]
    return energy
#
## create result
for i in range (1, len(dfEnergy)):
    date = dfEnergy['date'].values[i]
    hour = dfEnergy['hour'].values[i]
    energy1 = find_power(date,hour,df)
    dfEnergy.iloc[i,dfEnergy.columns.get_loc('energy')] = energy1
```